# Understanding Debezium

Tags: debezium

Provided a use case:

A stream processing architecture; 
Events go into Kafka then get processed by a job with a MongoDB sink.

Database name: `myWebsite`
Collection: `users`

and the job sinks `user` records in the `users` collection.

1. So Debezium will monitor the `users` collection for changes and, at every change, will produce events into Kafka on the topic `dbserver1.myWebsite.users` ? Assuming `dbserver1` is the name of the connector.
2. If so, then I can have a Kafka consumer that will consume from `dbserver1.myWebsite.users` topic and react to these events?
3. From what I understood the events produced by Debezium also contain the value of the database record? If its a change contains old/new value? If a db record is created the old is null?

I would like a some sort of confirmation of my understandings so far.
Thank you!

Comment: https://medium.com/groww-engineering/moving-from-hibernate-envers-to-debezium-bae4856c0e1b

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the answer are simple

1. Yes
2. Yes, it can be arbitrary kafka consumer or Kafka stream or you can query it with KSQL
3. Yes, Debezium records are composed from (not only) old values (`before`) and new (`after`) values. In case of `INSERT` only `after` is present in case of `UPDATE` both `before` and `after` are present (Postgres need a special setting for it) and in case of `DELETE` only `before` is present.

Comment: On 1.), the first part of the name will be whatever is given as value for the `mongodb.name` property. On 3), there is not `before` part in the events for MongoDB, as we cannot get that information. There is `after` for insert events and a `patch` element for updates. The event structure is described in detail in the Debezium MongoDB connector [documentation](http://debezium.io/docs/connectors/mongodb/#change-events-value).